# want to generate multiple numarical password and send it to sql server c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-3.0

I am using this code to generate unique code

```
public static string CreateRandomPassword()  //If you are always going to want 8 characters then there is no need to pass a length argument
    {
        string _allowedChars = "1234567899999";
        Random randNum = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);  //Don't forget to seed your random, or else it won't really be random
        char[] chars = new char[5];
        //again, no need to pass this a variable if you always want 8

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            chars[i] = _allowedChars[randNum.Next(_allowedChars.Length)];

        }
        return new string(chars);
```

And using this to send it to sql server

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sand = CreateRandomPassword();
        int num; 
        if ( int.TryParse(ids.Text,out num))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {

                string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["slxserv"].ToString();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO passwords (password) VALUES (@password) "))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",sand);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
```

Comment: what is the problem ? why do you need to insert num times your password ?

Comment: its generate the password but when trying to insert multiple the same password is added in diffrent row. for example if i create 6 password its create six password but the all the passwords are same

Comment: yes , insert means insert a new row in sql, and your password is generated one time before your loops

Comment: Like @Boo said, maybe you should put your CreateRandomPassword(); inside the for loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all put your `Random randNum = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);` out of the method `CreateRandomPassword()` and make it static

and how Boo said put this part into for loop `var sand = CreateRandomPassword();`

so final code will look like this

```
static Random randNum = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks); 
public static string CreateRandomPassword()  //If you are always going to want 8 characters then there is no need to pass a length argument
    {
        string _allowedChars = "1234567899999";

        char[] chars = new char[5];
        //again, no need to pass this a variable if you always want 8
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        chars[i] = _allowedChars[randNum.Next(_allowedChars.Length)];

    }
    return new string(chars);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num; 
        if ( int.TryParse(ids.Text,out num))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
            {
                var sand = CreateRandomPassword();
                string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["slxserv"].ToString();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon))

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO passwords (password) VALUES (@password) "))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",sand);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",sand);

with

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",CreateRandomPassword());

Comment: Opps, Just seen what Boo said. My answer is just an elaboration on his correct answer.

Comment: after making the changes result is same when i am generating 4 passwords its inserting four rows but with same passwords